# How to read file.xml from resources to NSString with format?

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, string, resources

Actually I have such a code:

```
NSString   *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"connect" ofType: @"xml"];
NSError    *error = nil;
NSString   *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path 
                                                         encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                            error: &error];
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:data, KEY, COUNTRY_ID];
```

which reads the connect.xml from resources. But on the formating the string (message) APP quits without displaying any errors. How can I read connect.xml from resources to NSString with format?

connect.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:WebApi" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:doQuerySysStatus>
      <sysvar xsi:type="xsd:int">1</sysvar>
      <country-id xsi:type="xsd:int">%d</country-id>
      <webapi-key xsi:type="xsd:string">%@</webapi-key>
    </ns1:doQuerySysStatus>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And defines:

```
#define KEY @"f7ff34df7a"
#define COUNTRY_ID 228
```

Comment: file connect.xml has %d and %@ inside

Comment: Are those the only occurrences of % in the whole file?

Comment: post connect.xml and more code (specifically, KEY and COUNTRY_ID).  Also, it may be time for line by line debugging, call NSLog after each statement to be sure that all values are as expected.

Comment: I've edited and added information about connect.xml

Comment: what is `error` after `stringWithContentsOfFile` and before `stringWithFormat`?

Comment: Oh, Geez!! I see the problem now! Of course it is an order of KEY and COUNTRY_ID. Sorry for my mix-up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think on the last line of code, the KEY and COUNTRY_ID variables are backwards.
In the data, COUNTRY_ID is first.

Comment: exactly! I've seen this a sec ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using JSON over XML, it is a much easier format to use.